# --flat-nodes osm2pgsql data import and TileMill

Tags: postgis, tilemill, osm2pgsql

This is more so a question regarding the import process with osm2pgsql and the use of the --flat-nodes option as  have seen that this is very useful especially when it comes to importing the entire planet into a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database. But what exactly is this file used for.

All I really understand about this is that it stores Nodes data in a separate file which is much smaller than the data that would imported into the database, but how is it used and are there any effects to how OSM data is handled in the database if this file is deleted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is flat-nodes file located?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302799/where-is-flat-nodes-file-located)